# Как установить количество элементов либо высоту первой колонки в двухколоночном списке?

Tags: html, css

Помогите разобраться с двухколоночным списком. В пример я навел код. Где то видел что "управлять" количеством элементов в колонке можно с помощью увеличения высоты самого списка, но как вижу это не получается.

Подскажите как сделать так что бы к примеру всегда 10 элементов было в первой и остальные во второй колонке. Можно ли указать конкретное число, или же это управляется высотой списка, но как то по другому, так как мой пример не работает.

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  columns: 2;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
<li>Item4</li>
<li>Item5</li>
<li>Item6</li>
<li>Item7</li>
<li>Item8</li>
<li>Item9</li>
<li>Item10</li>
<li>Item11</li>
<li>Item12</li>
<li>Item13</li>
<li>Item14</li>
<li>Item15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в кратце, то есть [св-во](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill) `columns-fill`, по умолчанию оно равно `balance`, что подразумевает равномерное заполнение контентом. Если поставить `auto`, то высота будет влиять на кол-во элементов в столбце

*P.S.*
*добавил `css` переменные для наглядности, что бы можно было считать автоматически с помощью функции `calc`. Можно обойтись и только добавление св-ва `columns-fill` и правильной высотой*

```css
:root {
  --columns-count: 2; /* кол-во столбцов */
  --row-height: 20px; /* высота строчки в столбце */
  --rows-count: 10; /* кол-во строчек */
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  column-fill: auto; /* теперь колонки будут заполняться до конца */
  columns: var(--columns-count);
  height: calc(var(--row-height)*var(--rows-count));
}

li {
  height: var(--row-height);
  line-height: var(--row-height);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
<li>Item4</li>
<li>Item5</li>
<li>Item6</li>
<li>Item7</li>
<li>Item8</li>
<li>Item9</li>
<li>Item10</li>
<li>Item11</li>
<li>Item12</li>
<li>Item13</li>
<li>Item14</li>
<li>Item15</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ставлю плюс. А что на счет кроссбраузености? Как с мобильными браузерами?

Comment: @kizoso https://webref.ru/css/column-fill

Comment: @kizoso андройд не умеет( как и св-во `columns`